# 2D OR Multidimensions Matrix Multiplication using a Vector In C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, stdvector, matrix-multiplication

I need to declare a vector which will contain 3 x 3 matrix. And Need to pass that vector to a function and need to perform a multiplication with the same vector. I know, I am not going in a proper way. But I am not able to figure out the problem. I am hoping some direction about 2d Matrix vector Multiplication.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void display(vector<vector<int>> &vec)
{
    for (int i = 0; vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++)
        {
            cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
vector<vector<int>> matMultiply(vector<vector<int>> &vec)
{
    for (int i = 0; vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++)
            vec[i][j] = 0;
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < vec.size(); i++)
            {
                vec[i][j] *= vec[i][k] * vec[k][j];
                cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
        return vec;
    }
}
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> matrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    display(matrix);
    matMultiply(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is storing the result of the multiplication in the same vector, just create a new 3x3 vector and do the calculation, it will work. Also return the final vector after the for loop at the end of the function

Comment: can you please, make an example, how can I do it?

Comment: Check Taimur Answer's it should suffice. If you want to the matrix Multiplication of any generic square vector then instead of 3 used vec.size()

Comment: It became apparent after reformatting that your inner `for` : `for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++)` have one statement `vec[i][j] = 0;` as a body. I think it was not your intention.

Comment: @Özgür Murat Sağdıçoğlu .. I did it, because to initialize ```vec[i][j] = 0;``` to 0 and Update the matrix result.

Comment: Please clarify if you want a function that *modifies* `vec` into its "square" or a function that *returns* the square of the passed matrix, without modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

Because matrix multiplication requires multiple matrix values to compute the value at a single index, you need some way to store the intermediate result. probably in another `vector`. You need to create a new `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` inside the `matMultiply` function. It should look something like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matMultiply(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &vec){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result(3, std::vector<int>(3));
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < result.size(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < result.size(); k++){
                result[i][j] += vec[i][k] * vec[k][j];
            }
        }   
    }
    return result;
}
```

Since you are not modifying the parameter(s) of the function, you should add `const` to have extra compile time checking in case you accidentally modify it in the function body.

You should remove the `cout` statements because they do not belong to the `matMultiply` function. The job of display the result belongs to the `display` function, which means you should pass the result of `matMultiply` as an argument to the display function in your `main` function.

Your `main` function should now look something like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    display(matrix);
    // Now you'll pass the result of `matMultiply` which is the
    // `result` matrix to the display function to display the result
    display(matMultiply(matrix));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am learning C++. Any kinds of suggestion would be great support for me. if I want to return this result to the display function, how Can I Do that?... I know I should try it myself. Any idea will save my time

Comment: @JohnMike I have edited the original answer. Please refer to it.

Comment: can you please next answer below.